# Read multiple CSV file and convert to excel and Append the File Name to the row after reading of each file using python pandas

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to read the multiple csv file and covert it to excel file using pandas in python, after reading of each csv file need to add a file name in the row.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7gMM.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You seem to have forgotten to post the Python code that's causing a problem

Comment: in addition to above comments, - would suggest to keep `Filename` as a separate column, not a row

Comment: path = os.getcwd()
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))

wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active
dfs = []
for csv_file in csv_files:
    pdval = pd.read_csv(csv_file)
    dfs.append(pdval)
df_concat = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=False )
df_concat.to_excel("output.xlsx")

Comment: from this code, I read the multiple csv file and concat to the excel file, but my requirement is while concating(convert csv to excel ) of each csv file i need one empty row(in excel, not a column but row) for which I need to add the file name of CSV

Comment: Like in the image which is attached above, the title should be at the top and next line should be file name and the values of CSV first file  and  second csv file name and the values of that file.